# How to display a list of possible value in an Excel user defined function?

Tags: excel, vba

i've created some user defined function in Excel, which a list of possible parameter. 
Suppose i have a GetCustomerRevenue function with 2 parameters:

```
GetCustomerRevenue(Year as Integer, CustomerName as String)
```

Obviously, users don't know 'precisely' name of all customer, so they have to digit it correctly..with a great possibility to be wrong!

Is it possible, in some way, to 'show' the list of all customers when i click the function name, when i positioned to the 'customerName' parameter (maybe taken from an hidden sheet, previously filled with customers list ) ?

Thanks

Comment: have you considered this being a bad design? Why not allow user to select a customer from a list and then click a button or something to generate the revenue?

Answer (score 0):

Rework your function to require a customer name rather than a customer number.  Then do the lookup within the function.  Minimal likelihood of error.